# cancel jquery validation and response.redirect on asp:imagebutton

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an form that uses JQuery for validation on some textboxes. I have an asp imagebutton that redirects to another page when clicked and is effectively the 'cancel' button with the response.redirect set in the code behind.

The problem I am having is when I click this button, the validation is disabled (as required) but the page is not redirecting as it should. Here is my JQuery code that disables validation:

```
$(function() {

    $("#btnBack").click(function() {

        $("#form1").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
        $("#form1").submit();

        return false;
    });

});
```

and the code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Response.Redirect("SC_ReferralList.aspx?PID=" & strPID)
End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I get the page to redirect without validation when I click the button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the code. I got it to work the way I wanted. This is my working function:

```
$(function() {

    $("#btnBack").click(function() {

        $("#form1").validate().cancelSubmit = true;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class of cancel to a submit button to suppress the validation

e.g

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

or if you have

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnBack" cssClass="cancle" text="Submit"/>
```

Notice that the button id `#btnBack` may change at runtime if you are using user control or master pages.

In this condition you can add `clientIdMode to static` on you button which will stop asp.net from changing the button ID.

More detail of client id mode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx